# Embed Knowledge tab or Chatter in the fully branded community with in Site.com or Visualforce

Tags: chatter, knowledge, customer-community

Please advise how to embed Knowledge Base, Chatter like in the first screenshot here http://blogs.developerforce.com/developer-relations/2013/10/communities-plus-site-dot-com.html
Is this done with site.com or visualforce?

What are the widgets that are used in site.com to embed knowledge or chatter or ideas modules if it is possible?

How it is done that web tab referencing to the site.com page automatically appears in the community menu? How community header is created in this example from blog?
Thanks in advance.